# How to set the name value of an input element, inside a transparent div, on drop?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable

I am dragging an item into an input element and setting the input element's name to that of the id of the dragged item. I then read the value of the input element's name to store in the DB. This works. However, I now want to make the input element draggable after it has been populated so it can be removed, if necessary. I do this by putting a transparent div over the input element so the div can be dragged, together with the input element, to remove it. Now I can not retrieve the input element's name value (or the input element's name value is not set). I believe the latter to be the case.

This works:
Create the table:

```
newRows +=      "<table name ='activityTable'>";
newRows +=          "<tbody id='activity2Tablebody' name='test1'>";
newRows +=              "<tr>";
newRows +=                  "<td class='dropValue' name='test2'>";
newRows +=                      "<div class='dragabbleRemove'>";
newRows +=                          "<input class='droppableItem activityWidth' name='test3' disabled></input>";//Droppable Activity Class
newRows +=                      "</div>";
newRows +=                  "</td>";
newRows +=              "</tr>";
newRows +=          "</tbody>";
newRows +=      "</table>";
```

On drop set the value of name property to the value of the id property of the dragged item:

```
draggableId = (draggable.prop('id'));
droppable.prop('name', draggableId);
```

Retrieve the value of the name property:

```
alert ("$(this).find('input').attr('name'): " + $(this).find('input').attr('name'));//id value
```

I then put a transparent div over the inputs elements so the div can be dragged to remove it:

```
newRows += "<div class='dragabbleRemove'><div>&nbsp;</div>";
newRows +=      "<input class='droppableItem activityWidth' name='test3' disabled></input>";//Droppable Activity Class
newRows += "</div>";
```

Now this returns blank:

```
alert ("$(this).find('input').attr('name'): " + $(this).find('input').attr('name'));//id value
```

I suspect that the following line needs to be changed to set the input element's name value; however, I can not find out what it needs to change to (the correct code):

```
droppable.prop('name', draggableId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I put some displays in and the lines:

```
draggableId = (draggable.prop('id'));
droppable.prop('name', draggableId);
```

are working.

Eventualy after much trial and error I replaced:

```
alert ("$(this).find('input').attr('name'): " + $(this).find('input').attr('name'));//id value
```

with:

```
$(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function(index,elem){
    alert(elem.name);
});
```

And added "type='text'" to the input element.